# Java OOP constants ref or get method

Tags: java, oop

I have faced next dilemma: Which one is better, to get prop from directly constants file or to create private prop with getter?

```
public class Warrior {
    ...
    public void attack() {
        this.setDamage(this.getDamage() + Constants.WARRIOR_DAMAGE_BONUS_POINT);
    }
}
```

vs

```
public class Warrior {
    private int damageBonusPoint;
    public Warrior() {
        this.damageBonusPoint = Constants.WARRIOR_DAMAGE_BONUS_POINT;
    }
    public int getDamageBonusPoint() {
        return damageBonusPoint;
    }
    public void attack() {
        this.setDamage(this.getDamage() + this.getDamageBonusPoint());
    }
}
```

Which one is better and why? What will you recommend?

Comment: I dislike both. I'd pass `damageBonusPoint` by `Warrior`'s constructor.

Comment: It seems like a difference that doesn't make a difference to me.  I would say that the second approach requires that you be consistent across all your classes.

Comment: The second approach doesn't seem to add any value with the added layer of indirection.  Unless `Warrior` needs to expose that getter method for other reasons as well?  Should `Warrior` own that constant entirely then?

Comment: @David I do not understand your question

Comment: @TeodorKolev: Well, what additional reasons do you have to add the `getDamageBonusPoint()` method?  What other objects use it and why?  If nothing outside this one instance uses it then (1) it shouldn't be `public` and (2) it probably shouldn't exist at all.  As for the constant itself, what else uses *that*?  Conceptually, should that constant be part of the `Warrior` class, or does it apply to other things as well?  Having a general catch-all `Constants` class is often a code smell.  Most things have a more appropriate home within the domain.

Comment: No other objects instead this class use it

Comment: @David I'll go one further. Having a general catch-all Constants class is **always bad design**. **All** things have a more appropriate home within the domain.

Comment: @TeodorKolev: If this object, even just this operation, is indeed the *only thing* which uses that constant at all then you certainly don't need a `getDamageBonusPoint()` method.  Put that constant in this class, make it private, and use it directly in the single line of code that needs it.  The only purpose of that constant is to draw attention to a hard-coded value by moving it out of the logic and into somewhere more visible and more obvious to the developer.

Comment: @David so it is totally ok to use first option?

Comment: @TeodorKolev: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be.  With the continued ongoing caveat that the `Constants` class *itself* should also be refactored properly into the rest of the domain.  (Though I *could* see a valid business case of wanting to keep "potentially changeable" hard-coded values in a single central location.  But still, as the developer I'd argue that future potential changes should focus on the business domain functionality rather than the values themselves and, thus, should start from the objects in the first place.)

Comment: @David pack this info and put it as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no advantage to assigning the value of the constant to a field, as you do in your second example, as it does not vary from instance to instance.

```
public class Warrior {
    private int damageBonusPoint;
    public Warrior() {
        this.damageBonusPoint = Constants.WARRIOR_DAMAGE_BONUS_POINT;
    }
    //...
}
```

If you're going to do this kind of "alias" at all, it should be a static final constant:

```
public class Warrior {
    private static final int DAMAGE_BONUS = Constants.WARRIOR_DAMAGE_BONUS_POINT;
    //...
}
```

But then this raises the question of why the constant isn't just present in the warrior class to begin with:

```
public class Warrior {
    private static final int WARRIOR_DAMAGE_BONUS_POINT = 3;
    //...
}
```

---

If we can agree on that, the question becomes:

```
public class Warrior {
    private static final int DAMAGE_BONUS = //...

    public void attack() {
        this.setDamage(this.getDamage() + DAMAGE_BONUS);
    }
}
```

vs

```
public class Warrior {
    private static final int DAMAGE_BONUS = //...

    public void attack() {
        this.setDamage(this.getDamage() + getBonus());
    }

    private int getBonus() {
        return DAMAGE_BONUS;
    }
}
```

In which case, the first is probably better simply because it's less verbose. Ultimately it doesn't really matter.

Comment: which one is the former first or second?

Comment: @TeodorKolev First.

Comment: so getters are useless?

Comment: @TeodorKolev: That *one* getter was useless.  Getters *in general* are very useful.

Comment: @TeodorKolev No. Getters are useful when you're exposing properties outside of a class. In this case, you're not doing that so the value is significantly reduced.

Comment: Is it because it is used only one time?

Comment: My constants file are static final, isn't it mistake to do new props in class?

Comment: @TeodorKolev That's worth considering but not really. The main reason you don't gain value from a getter is that no classes other than Warrior needs to know about it. If you need to change it for some reason, your changes will already be isolated to one class. That's more or less what it's all about - reducing the number of classes that will potentially need to change if you redefine the constant (for example, by renaming it).

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches make `Warrior` to be coupled with `Constants` class. That smells.

Use dependency injection instead. I'd pass `damageBonusPoint` by constructor:

```
public class Warrior {
    private final int damageBonusPoint;
    public Warrior(int dbp) {
        this.damageBonusPoint = dbp;
    }
    public int getDamageBonusPoint() {
        return damageBonusPoint;
    }
    public void attack() {
        this.setDamage(this.getDamage() + this.getDamageBonusPoint());
    }
}
```

and somewhere:

```
Warrior aragorn = new Warrior(Constants.WARRIOR_DAMAGE_BONUS_POINT);
```

Now, classes are not coupled anymore.

Comment: Right idea, wrong solution. The classes are only coupled because a `Constants` class is a bad idea. Moving the constant to the `Warrior` class is better. Using dependency injection is error-prone because different instances of `Warrior` might have different bonuses and that does not appear to be the intention in this case.

Comment: I must agree -  bad idea. I do not want to do that at all

Comment: You're right. But this is a more flexible design. Warriors creation should be inside a factory. Anyway, `damageBonusPoint` can be a Warrior's constant (static final)

Comment: Totaly of the question

Comment: So good luck testing that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
public class Warrior {
    public int getDamageBonusPoint() {
        return Constants.WARRIOR_DAMAGE_BONUS_POINT;
    }
    public void attack() {
        this.setDamage(this.getDamage() + this.getDamageBonusPoint());
    }
}
```

Its slightly better, because you can change `getDamageBonusPoint` without changing `attack`.

Better way: make `DamageCalculator`, pass in warriors stats and get damage value.

Comment: This did not answer my question

Comment: This is just a variation of my second option

Comment: Please, read last two sentences. And, by the wall, whole programming is one big variation.